# jQuery: giving the focus after showing a tab

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to give the focus to a field after showing a (Bootstrap) tab but
it doesn't work:

```
 $.fn.checkError = function(elem) {
   
   ...

   $('#myTab a[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');
   $('#firstname').focus();
 };
```

The field is not highlighted and doesn't seem to get the focus.
Can someone help me ?

EDIT: the html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
        <a class="nav-link" id="tab2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="true">Licences</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2-tab">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show html code  or it would be easy to test if you can create working code.

Comment: @Swati Here it is.

Comment: I have [tested](https://jsfiddle.net/dwv9srLk/) not seeing that behaviour .

Comment: That's probably because the checkError function is called through AJAX whenever the validator fails. The behaviour is different.

Comment: is it possible for you to create that behaviour ? because its hard to suggest anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the solution thanks to the @heatherhtml answer.
Here's the code:

```
 $.fn.checkError = function(elem) {
   
   ...

   $('#myTab a[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');
   $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {   
       $('#firstname').focus();
   });
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Bootstrap tab "on shown" event, so the focus is set after the tab is shown.

Most likely your tab content is not visible on the page before focus is called.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/list-group/#events

```
$('#myTab a[href="#tab2"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {   
   $('#firstname').focus();
})
```